# Syntax for range function in Python

Tags: python, range

the range function has syntax range(start,stop,step) and returns a sequence based on the arguments. Please explain the syntax range(10)[2:6][2]

range(10) is identical to range(0,10,0). what is happening with '[2:6][2]?

thanks

entering range(10)[2:6][2] evaluates to 4, but I don't understand why.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `range()`, you can slice lots of things in Python.

Answer (score 0):

The range function in Python has the syntax range(start, stop, step) and generates a sequence of numbers starting from start, up to but not including stop, with a step size of step. In the case of range(10), this generates a sequence of numbers starting from 0 and up to but not including 10, with a step size of 1. Note that the default value for the *start* parameter is 0 and the default value for the *step* parameter is 1, so range(10) is is identical to range(0,10,1) rather than range(0,10,0) as you indicated in your post.

You can find documentation for the range built-in function at: http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range

The square brackets after the range function are used to index the resulting sequence. For example, range(10)[2:6] returns a sub-sequence of numbers starting from the 3rd element (index 2) and up to but not including the 6th element (index 5), which in this case is [2, 3, 4, 5].

The second set of square brackets then indexes this sub-sequence, returning the 3rd element. Therefore, the expression range you provided evaluates to 4.

You can find documentation for the slicing syntax at: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Comment: perfect answer, but where is that explained in documentation? (feeling stupid)

Comment: range function is described at : https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range. Note that range(10) is identical to range(0,10,1) rather than range(0,10,0)

Comment: The syntax for slicing can be found at: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html

Comment: @ThomasMathewDavidLoeff  This particular syntax probably isn't explained in the documentation because there isn't really a practical use for it.  Even `range(2, 6)[2]` doesn't have a practical use.

Answer (score 0):

`range(param)` is a build-function that generate a list. The param is the lenght of number of list.
So you have a list of 10 numbers. From 0 to 9. Remenber arrays become at the 0 position.
Then you slice the list with `[start,end, jumps]`. You slice the list.
The result is 2,3,4,5.
After that you call the number at position [2].

- Beginning from 0 => 2
- Next position 1 => 3
- Then position 2 => 4